# Future of Google Closure open source project

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I love using the Closure library and the ideas behind using the Closure Compiler with the library.  I've used it in several projects already, such as [Post This For Me](https://www.postthisforme.co.uk/). A resent project.

I'm thinking about using Closure on a huge project I've got coming up where I'll be working with lots of developers who aren't as up to speed as me.

One thing I don't like about using Closure is the lack of good documentation, help and examples across the web.

My question is, what is the future of the open source Closure project?  Has Google given up on it?  I know it's used an awful lot inside Google but I rarely see it being used elsewhere on the web.  Should I steer my team towards using it or might I be making a huge mistake?

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.  Hope maybe some Googlers might see this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, what is the future of the open source Closure project? Has Google given up on it?

The project is still very active - inside Google as well as out. I know of several large organizations who use it external to Google. As an external contributor to the Closure-compiler project, I have a bi-weekly video call with the rest of the project team.

> One thing I don't like about using Closure is the lack of good documentation, help and examples across the web.

Yes this is an issue - specifically with Closure-library. The code itself is highly self-documenting, however, the official documentation of the API is out of date and needs regenerated. This is something I raised directly to contacts in Google so hopefully it will be fixed soon. The API documentation is generated directly from comments in the source code, so it's all still there though.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean about the comments in the code.  I've found those extremely useful and this is actually my preferred method of documenting myself.  However, I find generally finding out which object to use for what and generally knowing where to look for an answer difficult.  Some of those code comments could also be much longer with more explanation or examples.

Comment: As a user of Closure I'd very much like to be able to contribute to the in-code documentation if not the code itself.  Where can I go to get involved?

Comment: The project is hosted on github https://github.com/google/closure-library

Comment: one thing that helps me is that I use my IDE (emacs) to grep the closure library on my local machine.  I don't even go to the online documentation anymore.